# What is a key server (R installation)

Tags: r, installation, keyserver

I am trying to install an old version of R for my computer (os Ubuntu 20.04). Related to this topic I always find that I require to doing it a "key_server". In this context: 1) what is a key server, 2) Which is its purpose, 3) How could be obtained exactly.

Comment: I think you're talking about `apt-get` and having to deal with package signatures. Is that right?

Comment: Notably, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt-key.8.html and https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html. And if that is what you're talking about, and you still have issues, I'd think this question might need to migrate to https://askubuntu.com.